# forward declare typedef'd struct

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I can't figure out how to forward declare a windows struct. The definition is

```
typedef struct _CONTEXT
{
 ....
} CONTEXT, *PCONTEXT
```

I really don't want to pull  into this header, as it gets included everywhere.

I've tried

struct CONTEXT

and

struct _CONTEXT

with no luck (redefinition of basic types with the actuall struct in winnt.h.

Comment: You should post exactly what you've tried.  `struct _CONTEXT;` shouldn't produce an error, but it's not particularly useful by itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
extern "C" { typedef struct _CONTEXT CONTEXT, *PCONTEXT; }
```

You need to declare that `_CONTEXT` is a `struct`. And declare it as `extern "C"` to match the external linkage of windows.h (which is a C header).

However, you don't need to provide a definition for a `typedef`, but if you do, all definitions must match (the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)).

EDIT: I also forgot the extern "C".

Answer (score 1):

Not solution but workaround:

```
// h-file
struct MyContext; // forward decl
void f(MyContext * pContext); // use pointer


//cpp-file
#include <windows.h>
struct MyContext {
   CONTEXT cont;
};

void f(MyContext * pContext)
{
   CONTEXT * p_win_cont = & pContext->cont;
   // use p_win_cont
   // ....
}
```